# creating a slider using a matrix field

Tags: matrix

When creating a slider on my home page i had set the slider up as a channel, this allowed me to edit the channel and create a limit on how many slides where published. I was using the method of content -> publish -> slider to create a new slider. I would like to create a slider using a matrix field. I have create a variable group that allows me to edit the homepage and one of those variables is a matrix field, this is what i would LIKE to use to function my slider. How do i call the slider into my code correctly via a matrix field. Really my question is how does EE know im calling my matrix data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saying

> I created a variable group

I suppose that you are using Low Variables. That's generally the approach I take. Using Low variables, you just have to display the variable in your template using a tag pair and then use the normal matrix tags.

**Sample code:**

Low variable is called {lv_homeslider}

Matrix columns are called {matrix_slide_img}, {matrix_slide_url}, {matrix_slide_text}

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_homeslider"}
    {matrix_slide_img}
    {matrix_slide_url}
    {matrix_slide_text}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Hope that helps

EDIT: using low variables to the fullest

- [Replacing Snippets](http://jamiepittock.com/words/2012/apr/11/expressionengine-snippets-low-variables/)
- [Enhance flexibility of EE for devs and users](http://themetaq.com/articles/my-top-five-ways-low-variables-extends-ees-flexibility)
- [Small video detailing some use cases](http://www.mediasurgery.co.uk/video-episodes/expressionengine/low-variables)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. LV is a wonderful addon, useful for many many things: replacing snippets, featured content, washing dishes, etc. Edited answer with two useful links on the topic